# Fix Lego M Motor - The hooks aren't budging

Tags: motor, power-functions, repair, disassembly

I have a Lego M motor that is broken. I'm following the instructions [here](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-fix-LEGO-M-motor/) to try to fix it but the little tabs that hold the plastic frame together just won't budge no matter how hard I'm pushing them ([4:20 in the video](https://youtu.be/9y-k5yYG2hY?t=260)).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to take this thing apart? I'm deforming the plastic on the tabs since I'm pushing so hard with a screwdriver with a star head on the end and they look terrible now.

Comment: Related: https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/what-is-inside-the-lego-powered-up-m-motor . You have removed the bottom phillips screw first, *right*?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: In the comments of that video, the author responded to a similar issue : instead of using a screwdriver, you might jiggle the housing from side to side, while pulling, to get it to separate. Haven't tried this myself. All credit to the author of that video if this works.

Comment: maybe jncraton need to be an answer for you