# Fixing a LEGO M Motor connector

Tags: motor, repair, electronics, powered-up, disassembly

I have several broken ["Powered Up" M motors](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/10367/what-is-inside-the-lego-powered-up-m-motor) and I took one apart to see what was wrong. I ended up snipping off a section of the wire and re-soldering it back together but testing with an Ohm meter results in infinite resistance between the connector pins and the soldered points in the motor. So I took the connector apart (nearly destroying the thing), and I removed the wire and snipped an inch off. Using an Ohm meter now shows 0 resistance through the wire.

I have a problem putting the connector back together now. I put the pins back in place on the plastic pieces and then pressed the plastic pieces back in place with the hopes that the metal pins pierce the wires and allow for electricity to flow. It's not working.

Anyone here have any experience putting the connectors back together or pointers to resources on how people did it? I haven't found anything so far applicable for the M motor.

Comment: A quick search sends me to https://www.biasedlogic.com/index.php/lego-powered-up-connector/ - it's possible to 3d-print a new male connector and solder it.

Comment: I thought about the 3d printing too. Just adding the wire to the connector though is very difficult because the pins have these little spikes that pierce through the wire to complete the circuit.

Comment: You mean the male connectors have to be [crimped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimp_(joining)), like male [RJ45 connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#8P8C)? The usual way to repair a crimp-on connector is to just replace it with a new one, and apply a specialized tool to crimp. :-(

Comment: I think I kind of got it. I pressed down really hard and the wire did get pierced by the spikes on the bottom part of the connector. The top spikes aren't working but I think I'll let that slide.

Comment: Can you share a picture?

Comment: Have you tried asking LEGO for a replacement?